# PuTTY Serial `logout` or `exit` alternative

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, putty

When using `PuTTY` connected to a SSH session, upon entering `exit` or `logout` command, the connection is terminated and `PuTTY` is disconnected.

I'm designing an embedded ANSI/VT100 compatible terminal server, and I was wondering if there is a way to send something like a `Break` signal to `PuTTY` in order to make it disconnect and close the serial connection.

Is this possible? Or `PuTTY` doesn't handle serial connections in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `logout` command (`exit` command of the top-level shell sessions runs `logout`) does not send any command to PuTTY to terminate the connection. The `logout` command terminates the connection from server-side.

Check PuTTY event log after you type `exit`:

```
2017-10-16 08:10:38 Server sent command exit status 0
2017-10-16 08:10:42 Disconnected: All channels closed
```

Also, if you set *Close window on exit* to *Never* in PuTTY, you will get this after typing `logout`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CTRL-Break?  That's the PuTTY standard break command. In looking at the documentation, I see that only SSH2 supports the Break command.  Here's a link: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter3.html

Comment: I tried sending `0` and `26` key codes for CTRL-Break, but it didn't work. Do you mean that it only works in SSH mode?

Comment: From what I read in that documentation link yes, here's what it said:

**Break**
Only available in SSH-2, and only during a session. Optional extension; may not be supported by server. PuTTY requests the server's default break length.